# ggplot geom_col won't dodge time series data

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code I am using -

```
  g.volume <- ggplot (time_series, aes(x=quotedate, y=cv)) +  
            geom_col(position='dodge',fill='steelblue1', size=.8)      +
             geom_col(aes(x=quotedate, y=pv) ,position='dodge', fill='hotpink1', size=.8) +

  labs(x = "", y = "Call / Put  Volume") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank())  +  
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey", size=.5,linetype = 'dashed'))
```

The output is numerically correct but the two Y variables are stacked, not dodged side by side. None of the many examples on the web directly relate to time series data (X axis), but rather to a small number of categories/ My attempts to rotate the data were at best messy,  and didn't work.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and supply the data to reproduce your problem. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

How about this, you melt your data and plot `value`

```
dat <- melt(df, id.vars = c("quotedate"))
ggplot(data=dat,aes(x= quotedate, y=value, fill=variable, color=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position ="dodge")+
  labs(x = "", y = "Call / Put  Volume") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank())  +  
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey", size=.5,linetype = 'dashed'))
```